# Get two responses in one post in express

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, express, response

I think I have silly question, but I have no idea how I can fix this. In one post in express I would like send to another server two requests and I would like to get two responses to client side (angular in my case). I try make two `res.send(body)` but I get an error `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` And my question: Is possible these two responses throw and get in one response?

```
router.post('/paynow', function(req, res){
    request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://secure.snd.payu.com/pl/standard/user/oauth/authorize',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: "xyz"
    },  function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
            console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(response.headers));
            console.log('Response:', body);
            res.send(body);
      }
    )
    request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://secure.snd.payu.com/api/v2_1/paymethods/',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'xyz'
        }}, function (error, response, body) {
                console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
                console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(response.headers));
                console.log('Response:', body);
                res.send(body);
        }
    ),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send two responses. But you can merge both requests result into one response. Try using promises:

```
router.post('/paynow', function(req, res){
  Promise.all([
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://secure.snd.payu.com/pl/standard/user/oauth/authorize',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: "xyz"
      },  function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) return reject(error)
        resolve(body)
      })
    }),
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://secure.snd.payu.com/pl/standard/user/oauth/authorize',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: "xyz"
      },  function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) return reject(error)
        resolve(body)
      })
    })
  ]).then(listOfResponses => {
    res.json(listOfResponses)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Great.... First of all you *Cannot Send more than one Response.*  i.e.  **res.send** **once & only once !!**...

So what you could do is...make priority of which should be executed first...in your case **authorize** first and then **paymethods**

So the correct sequence would be

```
$.ajax{ 
  url : /authorize,
  type : post,
  data : /same data,
  , success : function(response) {
         //within successs make pay method request as another ajax using the 
         //  response from previous authorize request


           $.ajax{
              url : /paymethods,
              data : response
           }
  }
}
```

similarly Separate your routes ..

```
router.post('/authorize', function(req, res){
    request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://secure.snd.payu.com/pl/standard/user/oauth/authorize',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: "xyz"
    },  function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
            console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(response.headers));
            console.log('Response:', body);
            res.send(body);
      }
    )}
```

and

```
router.post('/paynow', function(req, res){
       request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://secure.snd.payu.com/api/v2_1/paymethods/',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'xyz'
    }}, function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
            console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(response.headers));
            console.log('Response:', body);
            res.send(body);
    }
  )
}
```